# spawn is not a function

Tags: javascript, cypress, sybase

I created a before to run an update on a Sybase database before a certain test in Cypress, but the following error occurs when running
"spawn is not a function"

````
before(() => {
    var Sybase = require('sybase'),
    db = new Sybase('host', '4400', 'dbname', 'user', 'pass');

db.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);

    db.query("update ..... ", function (err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err);

        console.log(data);

        db.disconnect();

    });
});```
````

Comment: Did you implement the function "spawn"? Where do you call this function?

Comment: I didn't implement it, it's a sybase library.
I put the library code in this link if you want to take a look
http://dontpad.com/cy/sybase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package [node-sybase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sybase) requires NodeJS to run, since it calls spawn which is a Node function.

You'll need to add you sybase code to a [task](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task#Syntax) which is where Cypress runs Node code,

**/cypress/plugins/index.js**

```js
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('task', {
    sybaseQuery(queryString) {

      // sybase connection and query code here

      return null
    },
  })
}
```

**test**

```js
before(() => {
  cy.task('sybaseQuery', 'update...')
})
```

Comment: That way I can't leave the update scripts inside the test.js file? Here it only works with the script inside Index

Comment: `queryString` contains the update script. You pass it from the test to the task as a parameter, as shown above (2nd parameter).

Answer (score 0):

**/cypress/plugins/index.js**

```
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('task', {
    sybaseQuery() {

      var Sybase = require('sybase'),
        db = new Sybase('host', '4400', 'dbname', 'user', 'pass');

      db.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);

        db.query('', function (err, data) {
          if (err) console.log(err);

          console.log(data);

          db.disconnect();

        });
      });
      return null
    }
  })
}
```

**test**

```
it('Dado que esteja preenchido a data de ultima consulta e numero de prazo de entrega', () => {

cy.task('sybaseQuery',"update dbo.CARTAO_USU_CARTAO_COMPLEMENTO set nr_prazo_entrega_cartao = '25' where nr_cartao =  '6035740409054753'")
```